# Use two mongoDB databases in one SpringBoot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

My SpringBoot API is supposed to read data from a collection of one database and before returning response back, it is supposed to insert a document in a collection of another database.

I am looking for a quick and efficient way to do this. I searched and found that I can make two entries in my application.properties and create two different Mongo template connection using those. But I am looking for a more clean and compact way to do this (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Refer

https://github.com/Mohit-Hurkat/spring-boot-multi-mongo

it's by using two templates (but a clean way and simple to do this)

https://github.com/Mohit-Hurkat/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb

Comment: Mine is a LDAP secured DB. I am unable to find the right way to handle multiple templates using SimpleMongoDBFactory. Using the complete LDAP URI gives, unknown host exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use change stream concept in mongodb..

If you have any change in database it automatically drop the changes in another database

Comment: But that's when there's an change event (update, insert or delete) onto a MongoDb

Comment: Yes so there is only option you can take value and put it in a another db..